# Granting public access on ibm cloud storage via ibm cos sdk

Tags: ibm-cloud-storage

Im trying to create a bucket while making it public programmatically via the ibm-cos-sdk in python. IBM/AWS documentation says I have to do it like this.

```
response = cos.create_bucket(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            CreateBucketConfiguration={"LocationConstraint": COS_LOCATION},
            ObjectOwnership="ObjectWriter",
        )
 cos.put_public_access_block(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
                "BlockPublicAcls": False,
                "IgnorePublicAcls": False,
            },
 )
 cos.put_bucket_acl(ACL="public-read", Bucket=bucket_name)
```

This code creates a bucket but doesn't make it public. I noticed on AWS boto3 documentation there's an additional `ObjectOwnership` attribute that is passed to cos.create_bucket but that option is not available on ibm-cos-sdk. Anything I'm missing?